# Flutter Obj-C plug-in how to get an argument?

Tags: objective-c, flutter

This is what I'm using:

```
- (void)handleMethodCall:(FlutterMethodCall*)call result:(FlutterResult)result {
  if ([@"loadImage" isEqualToString:call.method]) {
    NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(call.arguments[@"filePath"], 0.8);
    result(@"success");
  } else {
    result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented);
  }
```

However, I'm not sure if it's `call.arguments`, that's what it is on Java.

How can I go about getting auto-completion for plugin writing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `call.arguments` is an [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary?changes=_4) (cf. Java `HashMap`), so you could extract a String argument with:

```
NSString *value = call.arguments[@"argName"];
```

Comment: Is this correct? Edit: `NSString *value = call.arguments[@"filePath"];` and the next line: `NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(value, 0.5);`

Comment: I'm not sure UIImageJPEGRepresentation accepts the file path instead of the file.

Comment: It looks like it takes a `UIImage` https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-save-a-uiimage-to-a-file-using-uiimagepngrepresentation

Comment: Looks like you can get that from a path with https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624123-imagewithcontentsoffile?changes=_3

Comment: Still didn't work, but your answer is correct from what I've asked, I will open another post, thanks.